# Enum between C++ and Java1.4

Tags: java, c++, enums

We are writing an interface in java, between two modules one is in C++(module A) and one in Java(module B). 
Module B was developed long ago in Java1.4. Enums are handled as Integers as there is no support for enums in Java1.4.

In C++, every datatype is kept in a structure like:(pls ignore the types of struct members)

```
struct data{
Type;
noOfValues;
Values;
}
```

While transferring Enums from module B to A, Type has to be kept as ENUM and the values to be filled with integer value. As of now, this is done with hard coded by keeping a list of enum attributes and with a special check.(This is done for prototyping)

Can anyone pls help, What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please tell us how " every datatype is kept in a structure " : the sample code yo gave is not valid C++.

Comment: This can be done as below: Type is an Enum with all the types like BOOL, INT, ENUM etc.. , noOfValues is an integer, gives the no of elements in Values. And 'Values' is of type union with all the types. According to the variable 'Type', the union 'Values' will be filled.